# How to use spirit's qi attributes properly?

Tags: c++, boost, qi

I want to parse something like "a=1;b=2;{c=3;d=4;}e=5;f=6;". My problem is how to handle the block within the '{}' chars.
The values within the block shall be parsed (but not propagated to attribute of r1) if ignoreBlock is true.

```
using namespace boost::spirit;
using namespace std;
bool ignoreBlock = true;
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, vector<pair<string, int>>()> r1;
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, pair<string, int>()> r2;
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, vector<pair<string, int>>()> r3;
r1 = *(r2 | (qi::eps(phoenix::ref(ignoreBlock)==true) >> qi::omit[r3]) | r3);
r2 = qi::as<string>()[+qi::alnum] >> '=' >> qi::int_ >> ';';
r3 = '{' >> *r2 >> '}';
string s = { "a=1;b=2;{c=3;d=4;}e=5;f=6;"};
vector<pair<string, int>> v;
phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), r1,  boost::spirit::ascii::space, v);
```

This code causes some error like:
`'static_cast': cannot convert from  const std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::pair<std::string,int>'`

How do I handle such conditional parts correctly?

Comment: The code compiles if using a simple int instead of the pair. It seems I need any traits. (But still don't know which).

Comment: I have a lot of trouble getting this working without resorting to semantic actions. What do you _actually_ want to achieve anyways? Because the input is clearly nested. If you /always/ need to ignore that, simplify the grammar. If not, I have many dozens of answers on [SO] which show how to use Spirit Qi to parse into recursive datastructures.

Comment: Oh, basically `*(r2 | qi::omit[r3] | r3)` synthesizes into something like `std::vector<boost::variant<std::pair<std::string, int>, boost::optional<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > > >`. Automatic conversions rules give you a lot more latitude than that, but this is basically what your starting point looks like

Answer (score 0):

Why do you bind `ignoreBlock` in the rules, when you don't have anything changing it during parsing?

```
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, vector<pair<string, int>>()> r1;
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, pair<string, int>()> r2;
r2 = qi::as<string>()[+qi::alnum] >> '=' >> qi::int_ >> ';';

if (ignoreBlock)
{
    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, void()> r3;
    r1 = *(r2 | r3);
    r3 = '{' >> *r2 >> '}';
}
else
{
    r1 = *(r2 | qi::lit('{') | qi::lit('}'));
}
```

This doesn't reject unbalanced parentheses, but can be adapted to.

Comment: The 'static' ignoreBlock was only to simplify the example. It changes dynamically in my real code. The question is why r1 = *(r2 | r3); fails to compile with:'static_cast': cannot convert from 'const std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::pair<std::string,int>'